# Json Result to List in ASP.net View

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, list, deserialization

This is my form in contact class

```
 <form method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="subid" autofocus="">
    </div>
      <button href="" class="btn btn-gm btn-success">View</button>
</fieldset>
```

> This is my code in controller and i have view called Contact

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Contact()
        {     

            return View();

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contact(string subid)
        {
            try
            {
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                string url = string.Format(BASE_URL + "Subjectstatus/{0}", subid);
                var json = webClient.DownloadString(url);
                var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                ViewBag.attendlist = js.Deserialize<List<attendlist>>(json);

                return View();


            }
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.con = "gg";
                return null;
            }

        }
```

This is my attendlist class

```
 public class attendlist
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")]   
        public string sid { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Subject")]
        public string sub { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        public string date { get; set; }
    }
```

This is Contact View im trying to loop it using for each

```
@foreach (var dd in ViewBag.attendlist)
{
    <h3>@dd.ID</h3> 

}
```

This is the error when im try to load contact view

[image]

Comment: You have never used JavaScriptSerializer defined as js variable. Deserialize your downloaded string.

Comment: yes i dont know to how to Deserialize with JavaScriptSerializer and get to the LIST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {           

        return View( new ViewContact() );

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(ViewContact contact)
    {
        try
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            string url = string.Format(BASE_URL + "Subjectstatus/{0}", contact.subid);
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(url);
            var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            attendlist list= js.Deserialize<attendlist>(json)

            contact.attendlist = list;             

            return View(contact);


        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.con = "gg";
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Class ViewContact

```
  public class ViewContact
  {
    public attendlist list { get; set; }
    public string subid { get; set; }
  }
```

And the foreach at the view

```
 foreach(var dd in Model.list){
          //your html view code
    }
```

The view

```
<form method="POST">
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.subid, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Email" }) >
</div>
  <button href="" class="btn btn-gm btn-success">View</button>
</fieldset>
```

*Note textboxfor , get the model atributte and it bind later it correctly to the action submit

*Note that now you have to pass a contect not a string to Contact(ViewContact contact) action

Comment: check if you have a good json when you do var json = webClient.DownloadString(url);

Comment: still no getting to my list

Comment: The problem is the viewbag i think because attendlist list= js.Deserialize<attendlist>(json) is not making error

Comment: You have to send return View(list); and set attendlist like a Model of your View, try it , then @foreach (var dd in Model)

Comment: If you can't send like a view the object, you have to build a VM object, to add the list of attendlist

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: it come up with error  dose not contain definition for attendlist

Comment: i just replace it for  public attendlist attendlist { get; set; } then i got Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in view

Comment: can you update your code, i don't understand which problem you have now

Comment: you have to add at the top of the View @model .... sintaxis , you know it i hope so

Comment: you have to use textboxfor lambda to create the input , i rewrite my answer

Comment: ok but when i ViewBag.test = json; and in Contact view <h5> @Viewbag.test  im getting correct filtered json response according to input value

Comment: my code is working fine im getting json response but in json format i need to convert to the list and loop in for loop to get data

Comment: try this --->> var list = serializer.DeserializeObject(json); -->replace  attendlist list= js.Deserialize<attendlist>(json) but it had to work , it's auto mapper

Comment: Can you copy the Json you get ?

Comment: Check my foreach , it had a fault  :  is Model.list , my mistake